# Query with multiple column conditions in single table

Tags: sql

My table consisting multiple columns data with combination of data and null values.Here i want to display only data not null value when i select for that i have write one query like below.

```
select Capability
     , BusinessStrategyMessaging
from tb_MBUPSheetData 
where (Capability is not null)
  and (BusinessStrategyMessaging is not null)
```

But it showing empty table not displaying table data.I want to satisfy two columns and display data when i select.

Please give me suggestions please.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Could you give a sample row that does not show up and should?

Comment: are you sure you're not looking for an OR condition instead of the AND condition in  the where clause to get where one or the other is null - this looks correct if you're trying to pull rows where both aren't null?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to show registries that is populated on your table based on the columns you put on your select. So there is NOTHING wrong with your query. The thing is that in your table there is NO registries that attend those two conditions:

```
    (Capability is not null)
and (BusinessStrategyMessaging is not null)
```

At least not at the same time. So I think what you want is one OR another. To do so you have to put your conditions as this:

```
(    (Capability is not null)
OR (BusinessStrategyMessaging is not null) )
```

Note that I put some extra parenthesis because if you have any other conditions it will not affect it.